# Constructing the retraction in the proof of Brouwer’s fixed point theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems

Let $r: B^n \to S^{n-1}$ be definied by:
$$r\left(x\right):=\frac{x-f\left(x\right)}{\left\lVert x-f\left(x\right)\right\rVert_2}\in S^{n-1}$$
($r\left(x\right)$ is the normed direction vector from $f\left(x\right)$ to $x$.)

Let $\lambda: B^n\to \mathbb{R}^+_0$ be defined by: $$\lambda\left(x\right) := - \left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle + \sqrt{1-\left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2 + \left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle^2}\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$$

Finally, let $F:B^n\to S^{n-1}$ be defined by:
$$F\left(x\right)=x+\lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right)$$
($F\left(x\right)$ is the intersection of the half-ray from $f\left(x\right)$ to $x$ with the sphere $S^{n-1}$ and $\lambda\left(x\right)$ is the corresponding scalar.)

My construction should follow the proof from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixpunktsatz_von_Brouwer#Beweisidee):

[image: Brouwer fixed point theorem retraction]

I now want to check that $F\left(x\right)$ actually lies in $S^{n-1}$.
\begin{align}
   \left\lVert F\left(x\right) \right\rVert_2^2 = &\left\langle F\left(x\right), F\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   = &\left\langle x+\lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right), x+\lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   = &\left\langle x, x+\lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   &+
   \left\langle \lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right), x+\lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   =&\left\langle x, x\right\rangle + \left\langle x, \lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   &+ \left\langle \lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right), x \right\rangle + \left\langle \lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right), \lambda\left(x\right)r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   =&\left\langle x, x\right\rangle + \lambda\left(x\right) \left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   &+ \lambda\left(x\right) \left\langle r\left(x\right), x \right\rangle + \lambda\left(x\right)^2\left\langle r\left(x\right), r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\newline
   =&\left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2 + 2\lambda\left(x\right) \left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle + \lambda\left(x\right)^2 \left\lVert r\left(x\right)\right\rVert_2^2 \overset{!}{=} 1\newline
   \Leftrightarrow \lambda_{1,2}\left(x\right) =&\frac{-2\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle \pm \sqrt{\left(2\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\right)^2 - 4\left\lVert r\left(x\right)\right\rVert_2^2 \left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2}}{2\left\lVert r\left(x\right)\right\rVert_2^2}\newline
   =&-\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle \pm \sqrt{\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle^2 - \left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2}
\end{align}

However, I am missing the 1 in the discriminant. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The quadratic in the third-to-last line has a $1$ on the right hand side. The quadratic formula is only for equations with a $0$ on the RHS - so you should subtract the $1$ first, and then the constant term in that quadratic is $\lVert x \rVert^2 - 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Izaak van Dongen.

\begin{align*}
\left\lVert F\left(x\right)\right\rVert_2=\ &\left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2 + 2\lambda\left(x\right) \left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle + \lambda\left(x\right)^2 \left\lVert r\left(x\right)\right\rVert_2^2 \overset{!}{=} 1\\
   \Leftrightarrow\ &\lambda\left(x\right)^2 + \left(2\left\langle x, r\left(x\right)\right\rangle\right) \lambda\left(x\right) + \left(\left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2 - 1\right) = 0\\
   \Leftrightarrow \lambda_{1,2}\left(x\right) =&\frac{-2\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle \pm \sqrt{\left(2\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle\right)^2 - 4 \left(\left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2-1\right)}}{2}\\
   =&-\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle \pm \sqrt{\left\langle x, r\left(x\right) \right\rangle^2 + 1 - \left\lVert x\right\rVert_2^2}
\end{align*}